# Can we connect a 32 bit Oracle server from a 64 bit client and vice a versa? 

Tags: database, oracle, 64-bit, 32-bit

Is it possible to connect a 32 bit Oracle server from a 64 bit client?

What about the opposite case?

Comment: Yes, of course. There are limits to the versions concerned, though. For example the latest servers do not talk to Oracle 7 clients anymore.

Comment: What client you install depends more on the applications that need to use the client than anything else.

Comment: 11g client can't connect to 8i.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can do that, there's no limitation regarding that (64-bit, 32-bit).

Reference: [Oracle 207303.1](https://82star.wordpress.com/2011/09/06/clientserver-interoperability-support-id-207303-1/) ([original link](https://support.oracle.com/CSP/main/article?cmd=show&type=NOT&id=207303.1), requires login)

Comment: See document 207303.1, on support.oracle.com, to see a matrix of supported clients and servers.  It says that 32-bit and 64-bit can be mixed.

Comment: @jonearles Thank you, I've added a reference to the documentation.